# Understanding Hadoop Packages and Classes

Tags: class, hadoop, package, avro

I have been using `CDH` and `HDP` for a while (both in the pseudo-distributed mode) on a VM as well as installing natively on Ubuntu. Although my question is probably relevant to all Projects within the `Apache Hadoop Ecosystem`, let me ask this specifically in the context of `Avro`.

What is the best way to go about figuring out what the different packages and the classes within the packages do. I usually end up referring to the Javadoc for the project (`Avro` in this case) but the overviews for packages and classes end up being awfully inadequate.

For e.g. Take two of the Avro packages: `org.apache.avro.specific` and `org.apache.avro.generic` These are used for creating `Specific` and `Generic` `Readers` and `Writers` (respectively) but I'm not a 100% sure what these are for. I have used the `Specific` Package for in cases when I have used `Avro` Code Generation and the Generic ones when I don't want to use code generation. However, I am not sure if that is the only reason for using one vs. the other.

Another example: The `Encoder\Decoder` Classes are used for low-level SerDe, the `DatumReader\DatumWrite` for a "medium-level" Serde while most application layer interactions with Avro will probably use `Generic\Specific` `Readers\Writers`. Without having struggled through the pain of using these classes, how is a user to know what to use for what?

Is there a better way to get a good overview of each package (clearly the javadoc is not well documented) and the classes within the package?

PS: I have similar questions for essentially all other `Hadoop` Projects (`Hive`, `HBASE` etc.) - the Javadocs seem to be grossly inadequate overall. I just wonder what other developers end up doing to figure these out.

Any inputs would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download the source code and skim through it to get the idea what it does. If there is javadoc, I read that too. I tend to concentrate on the interfaces that I need and move on from there, that way I put everything into context and it makes it easier to figure out the usage. I use the call hierarchy and the type hierarchy views a lot.

These are very general guidelines, and ultimately it is the time you spend with the project that will make you understand it.

Hadoop ecosystem is quickly growing and changes are introduced on monthly bases. that's why javadoc is not so good. Another reason is that hadoop software tends to lean towards the infrastructure and not towards the end user. People developing tools will spend time learning the APIs and internals while everybody else is kinda supposed to be blissfully ignorant of all those, and just use some high level domain specific language for the tool.